# Python grpc interceptor and user authentication

Tags: grpc, interceptor, grpc-python

I have a python grpc service that has API methods that need be aware of user information, such as username email address to do various filtering.

I have a python server-side grpc interceptor attached to the service that decodes the jwt (passed via the client's request context) for claims and verify the authenticity. The interceptor abort the call if the token is invalid and decode the list of claims from the token. But the thing is I need to be able to pass in the jwt claim information into my API methods so they can use that information to do filtering (and ideally I want to be able to attach the decoded username to the logs for all api calls in the interceptor).

It seems like, in the interceptor, I should be able to add the username claim decoded from the token to the context and pass it to the API method? But I have not found any documentation on how to modify the context.

My APIs do have access to the context with token and can decode for the claim themselves, but it seems weird to me add a decorator or method to decode the token to every API method definition.

Comment: I've not written interceptors in Python but, in Golang, in an Interceptor, you can grab the call's metadata from the context and I assume you could update this before invoking the handler; my auth handlers simply don't invoke the handler and return an error if the user is not auth'd. I assume the Python SDK has something similar.

Comment: I can read the context in the interceptor, but it appears to be read only. Is there a way you can modify it?

Comment: You've piqued my interest. I'm going to try this for myself. I've not used the Python SDK much. Have you tried pinging the SDK maintainers for help too? That may be productive. It's unfortunate that the gRPC documentation (generally) isn't more comprehensive.

Comment: I think (!?) `handler_call_details` may support `set_trailing_metadata` (see: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/4c8a0d91c6339977fb7fe9fbbcd29ea4f356a2c7/examples/python/interceptors/headers/request_header_validator_interceptor.py#L36)

Comment: No, that doesn't work.

Comment: I tried creating a new `HandlerCallDetails` as a way to add e.g. a new `metadatum` but there appears no methods to do that. I suspect you're correct and it's not possible. Perhaps file an issue on the gRPC repo?

Answer (score 1):

The grpc/python team are interested in read/write ability. From what I can see, the repository maintainer replied on [issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/26229#issuecomment-849028049), and the [examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/672f31c6ac18e527062b3b029b5a5fc032904696/examples/python/interceptors/headers/request_header_validator_interceptor.py) at grpc/python only show how to read, not write. So for now, it look's like there's no way to manipulate this through python implementation. For server side, the only choice to manipulate the client's payload is to do something at the Servicer.